# Telnet Client using PHP

Tags: php, windows-7, xampp, telnetlib

This is my code:

```
$socketConnection = @fsockopen ( "127.0.0.1", "23", $errorNumber, $errorString, 30 );
if ( ! $socketConnection )
{
    print '<b>Connection Failed</b><br />' . $errorString . '<br />' . $errorNumber;
}
else
{
    //stream_set_blocking ( $socketConnection, 0 );
    //stream_set_timeout ( $socketConnection, 10 );
    print '<b>Connection Success!</b><br />';
    fputs($socketConnection,'\r');
    sleep(1);
    $buffer = fread ( $socketConnection, 20 );
    $out='';
    for ( $i=0; $i < 20; $i++ )
    {
        $out .= $buffer [ $i ] ;
    }
        $response = trim ( preg_replace( "/^.*?\n(.*)\n[^\n]*$/", "$1", $out ) );
        echo $response;
        //$response = bin2hex($response);
        //hex2ascii('ff:fd:25:ff:fb:01:ff:fb:03:ff:fd:27:ff:fd:1f:ff:fd:00:ff:fb');
    fclose ( $socketConnection );
}
```

Now, when i execute the code, I get the output:

> ÿý%ÿûÿûÿý'ÿýÿý

and nothing else. What can be the problem? And how can I get this problem cleared. I am on win7 with xampp version 2.5

Moreover, I installed win7 telnet server on my system and I can telnet it from telnet command.

I used putty to telnet and here is what i got:
[image: putty login screenshot]

Comment: A telnet client can be written simply by using `fsockopen`.

Comment: What are you telneting ? What type of device/server ? Aren't you just misinterpreting received data ?

Comment: @castor: thats what i am asking you for. I am new to socket programing and can't interpret the results. Also I have mentioned in my question that the telnet server is the one which comes with windows 7.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: I have tried by simply using fsockopen, It does create the connection, but after that i can't get the response from server or should i say i dont know how to use fread to get the response.

Comment: You simply need to know what you should get from the server. Try it with putty and then analyze. I can't answer your question with such insufficient details of what you are working with.

Comment: Please answer all the questions @castor asked

Comment: @castor: added the description.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: added the description

Comment: Testing, testing... But can't find out what's wrong... I will take a deeper look, when I get a chance.

Comment: @castor: lets hope you get chance soon :P... I am really stuck here

Answer (score 0):

It's a part of the "auto-negotiation" for telnet clients...

It will help if you convert the characters to HEX, and then reference:

[The TELNET Protocol -- KB 231866](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231866)

Oh, and even though you said Microsoft, :

[www.eventhelix.com - EventStudio - TCP/IP Protocol Sequence Diagram Examples](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/networking/)

Specifically, these may help you visualize:

> ***High-level Telnet Client and Server Protocol Sequence Diagram***
>
> ***Telnet Protocol Context Diagram -- EventHelix.com/EventStudio 2.0***

Which you can find on the eventhelix.com page.

(*Note:  sorry for no links on the last two..., my rep is still too low on here...*  ;-)